# How to remove link from tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to display the tags on my Wordpress site,

```
<?php the_tags( $before, $sep, $after ); ?>
```

However it outputs

```
Tags: tag1, tag2 ....
```

I want to remove the 'Tags' lable that gets automatically put in front, as well REMOVE the link that is put on each tag (I want the word there but I don't want it linking to anything.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just and paste it inside the loop:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();

  $tags = array();
  if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      $tags[] = $tag->name;
    }
  }
  $newTags = implode($tags, ',');

  echo $newTags;
```

Comment: nice, works great, can I add a class in there so I can style them?

Comment: yes, you can add class or anything into the `foreach` loop where I iterated the post tags.

Comment: I'm new at this so it would look like implode($tags, 'tagstyles'); for a css class style .tagstyles